# Several different printed labels for the same bibliographical entry

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

After surfing this site for quite a while, I haven't found an answer for my question:

> While using `biblatex`, can I cite the same bibliographical entry with *several* different printed labels each time?

Suppose I have the following bibliographical entry on my `.bib` file:

```
@book{ele,
  author={Euclid},
  title={Elements}
}
```

Euclid's elements consist of thirteen different books. Imagine I want to cite a proposition from book 4. I would like to get printed something like [ELE4, Prop. 15]. Then after, I want to do the same but with one from book 8 and get printed [ELE8, Prop. 25]. In all cases (as I am using the `hyperref` package), I would like that one can still click on the printed label and that it would redirect to the same bibliography entry printed on the pdf.

How can one achieve this? I know that I can get printed [ELE, Prop. n] with `\cite[Prop. n]{ele}`, but maybe one could implement something working like `\cite[Prop. n]{ele}{CUSTOM}` to get printed [CUSTOM, Prop. n]?

For those people that might say “just use `\cite[Book n, Prop. m]{ele}` if you want to refer to a specific book”: I'm actually not interested on citing Euclid's *Elements*, but rather, Grothendieck's *Éléments de géométrie algébrique*: this work consist of several volumes and even several books needed to be printed encompassing the same volume. For this reason, I would like to get printed citations like [EGA IV₂, (2.1.10)], [EGA III₁, (1.3.1)] refering to the same bibliographical entry. (With Euclid's *Elements* the explanation seems easier to grasp.)

Comment: `biblatex` defines `\volcite[<prenote>]{<volume>}[<pages>]{<key>}` that lets you typeset something like "[Ari77, vol. 2, p. 23]". More complex stuff like "III₁" wouldn't be as easy, though - unless you type it in literally like that.

Comment: @moewe Okay, good to know. Anyway, I already knew how to obtain something like [EGA, vol. III, book 1, (1.3.1)]. But as I said, I would like to get [EGA III₁, (1.3.1)] (and analogous for the other citations), while referring in all cases to the same bibliographical entry.